# Rewriting $|z+2i|=\sqrt{2}|z+1|$ in $x+yi$ form with $x,y\in{}\mathbb{R}$

Tags: complex-numbers, curves

According to my prof, the above equation is equivalent to $$x^2+(y+2)^2=2((x+1)^2+y^2)$$ I don't see how he could come to this conclusion, any insight/help would be highly appreciated.

Edit: It's probably very basic and I feel embarrassed asking such a question on here but still, am desperate on to knowing how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}\lvert z+2i\rvert=\sqrt2\lvert z+1\rvert&\iff\bigl\lvert x+(y+2)i)\bigr\rvert=\sqrt2\bigl\lvert x+1+yi\bigr\rvert\\&\iff\bigl\lvert x+(y+2)i)\bigr\rvert^2=2\bigl\lvert x+1+yi\bigr\rvert^2.\end{align}Can you take it from here?

Comment: I figured that much earlier but couldn't proceed further :/

Comment: What do you think that $\lvert a+bi\rvert^2$ is?

Comment: Ah yes I got it. $a^2+b^2$ so in view of the original statement we get $x^2+(y+1)^2 = (x+1)^2+y^2$. Thanks a lot.

Comment: For the second time actually, you had answered one of my other questions before :)

Answer (score 1):

If $z=x+iy$ then $|z|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

Also, $z+2i=x+i(y+2)$ which leads to $|z+2i|=\sqrt{x^2+(y+2)^2}$

And, $z+1=(x+1)+iy$, which similarly leads to $\sqrt 2|z+1|=\sqrt 2 \sqrt{(x+1)^2+y^2}$

Try equating these then squaring them.